# PostGIS Error : size of index too small

Tags: index, postgis

### PostgreSQL 13.5, PostGIS 3.2, Windows Server 2012.

My main goal is to create an **unique index** on a column containing geometries.

Here is the table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS geometrie.uniteobservation_geom
(
gid bigint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
gid_unobs bigint,
geometrie character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
CONSTRAINT gid_pk PRIMARY KEY (gid)
)
```

Here is the query to fill the table (following some threads seen here) :

```
insert into geometrie.uniteobservation_geom (gid_unobs, geometrie) 
select gid, md5(st_asBinary(geom)) from 
(select 
 u.gid,
 u.geom
FROM activite.uniteobservation u
 JOIN ara.departements d ON st_intersects(u.geom, d.geom)) as ssreq;
```

Then I can't create an index on geometrie column :

```
create unique index if not exists idx_geom_unobs on geometrie.uniteobservation_geom (geometrie)
```

returns `the row index requires 10848 octets, maximum size is 8191`

I have tried to shorten the values with `left(md5(st_asBinary(geom)), 10)`, but it failed. And since there are already thousand rows and there will tens of thousand rows, I don't want to shorten the values much !

What solutions can I try to create an index that fixs my goal ?

Comment: That is not a PostgreSQL error message. Is this a fork?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what a fork is.

Comment: A fork of a software like PostgreSQL is if someone takes the PostgreSQL code and modifies it. Like most hosted PostgreSQL-like databases.

Comment: ok Thanks. So it is not a fork, just a regular instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your query shows only MD5 values inserted into the column, which wouldn't be a problem.  But somewhere there must be a much bigger value in the table.

You can find the ten largest values with a query like

```
SELECT gid, length(geometrie)
FROM geometrie.uniteobservation_geom
ORDER BY length(geometrie)
LIMIT 10;
```